How to Combine multiple data sets based on a single column horizontally
Below datasets are written within "WITH" Clause



Date
Data 1




14-Nov
abc


15-Nov
def






Date
Data 2




14-Nov
123


15-Nov
456






Date
Data 3




14-Nov
!@#


15-Nov
$%^



Need the final result as below



Date
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3




14-Nov
abc
123
!@#


15-Nov
def
456
$%^



Above result can be achieved through join , but the problem I am facing is that these individual result sets are part of each data set within a query using "WITH" clause.
For one date it is working fine , unable to collate for multiple dates.
Any view on this.

Got the results using
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, 'abc' AS Data1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '15-Nov', 'def'
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, '123' AS Data2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '15-Nov', '456'
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, '!@#' AS Data3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '15-Nov', '$%^'
)
SELECT
    cte1.Date,
    cte1.Data1,
    cte2.Data2,
    cte3.Data3
FROM
    cte1
JOIN
    cte2 ON cte1.Date = cte2.Date
JOIN
    cte3 ON cte1.Date = cte3.Date;


UNION ALL and GROUP BY?

Couldn't go for Union and Group by due to performance issues

Just join all tables by Date

Got the expected results using this                                                                      WITH
cte1 AS (
SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, 'abc' AS Data1
UNION ALL
SELECT '15-Nov', 'def'
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, '123' AS Data2
UNION ALL
SELECT '15-Nov', '456'
),
cte3 AS (
SELECT '14-Nov' AS Date, '!@#' AS Data3
UNION ALL
SELECT '15-Nov', '$%^'
)
SELECT
cte1.Date,
cte1.Data1,
cte2.Data2,
cte3.Data3
FROM
cte1
JOIN
cte2 ON cte1.Date = cte2.Date
JOIN
cte3 ON cte1.Date = cte3.Date;

@indurani is this fixed then?

Yes Fixed , Thank you.

@Indu Could you please create an answer rather than a comment with your solution? Then accept this answer, so the question is marked as resolved.

Agreed. Don't put the solution in the request, but write an answer instead that you accept. As to the query: If your DBMS supports the syntax (you forgot to tag you request with your DBMS; please do this), then you may prefer select * from cte1 join cte2 using (date) join cte3 using (date). This is standard SQL syntax, and with it you can easily turn all the inner joins into full outer joins later, in case you need that.
